# Перенести текст из таблицы

Tags: swift, инспекция-кода, uitableview

Добрый день, как перенести текст из таблицы в другое окно `View Controller`.

Не могу понять, что не так сделал, на строке                     `nextViewController.labelSpecieText = (cell?.textLabel?.text!)!`
появляется ошибка:

> Value of type 'SpeciesTableViewController' has no member
>   'labelSpecieText'

Ниже представлен код:

```
class SpeciesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var tableData = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SpeciesPets", ofType: "plist")

        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)

        tableData = dict!.objectForKey("Scpecies") as! [String]    
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellSpecie", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

        cell.textLabel!.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "editNamePat" {

            if let navController = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
                if let nextViewController = navController.topViewController as? SpeciesTableViewController {
                    let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
                    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path!)
                    nextViewController.labelSpecieText = (cell?.textLabel?.text!)!
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: у класса SpeciesTableViewController нет переменной labelSpecieText, судя по коду в вопросе так и есть.